# problem when extract subframe based on date

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe 'card_df'.
I would like to extract a train dataset based on 'DateTrans' column.

train dataset must contain only rows where 'DateTrans' are between('01/01/2019') and ('31/06/2019')

I tryed with this code :

```
# Create the train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(card_df.loc[card_df['DateTrans'].between('01/01/2019','31/06/2019', inclusive=False)].drop(["RapprochementFraude"], axis=1),
                                                    card_df.RapprochementFraude)
```

But the problem is that the train dataset contains rows where 'DateTrans' are outside the interval that i Precise It below.

```
X_train['DateTrans']



2044    27/08/2019
959     25/05/2019
1669    27/03/2019
498     28/05/2019
1198    28/05/2019
           ...    
1985    25/07/2019
435     29/01/2019
291     25/07/2019
107     26/06/2019
29      25/07/2019
Name: DateTrans, Length: 30048, dtype: object
```

any idea please to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your *dateTrans* is a string and not `datetime` type.

Try to convert it by:

```
card_df['dateTrans']= pd.to_datetime(card_df['dateTrans'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass to `pd.Series.between(left, right, inclusive=False)` dates in `str` format, it returns indices of strings of `Series` that bigger than `left` string, and smaller than `right` string. To correctly compare strings that represent dates you should use `Year-Month-Day` notation.

For example:

```
print('31/06/2019' > '25/10/2019') # Day-Month-Year notation
# True   
print('2019/06/31' > '2019/10/25') # Year-Month-Day notation
# False
```

You can solve your problem by changing notation to Year-Month-Day:

```
import pandas as pd

card_df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='20190101', end='20191025')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), 
                       columns=['DateTrans'])

print(card_df.head()
#     DateTrans
# 0  01/01/2019
# 1  02/01/2019
# 2  03/01/2019
# 3  04/01/2019
# 4  05/01/2019

cards_subgroup = card_df[card_df['DateTrans'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.split('/')[::-1])).between('2019/01/01','2019/06/31', inclusive=False)]

print(cards_subgroup.head())
#     DateTrans
# 1  02/01/2019
# 2  03/01/2019
# 3  04/01/2019
# 4  05/01/2019
# 5  06/01/2019

print(cards_subgroup.tail())
#       DateTrans
# 176  26/06/2019
# 177  27/06/2019
# 178  28/06/2019
# 179  29/06/2019
# 180  30/06/2019
```